# Ошибка AJAX при установке Drupal

Tags: drupal

При установке Drupal на ПК вылезает ошибка:
**An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /mydrupal/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard&id=1&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: error
ReadyState: 0**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли браузера пишет: **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
7Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
install.php:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received**

Страница error page пишет:
**The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by standard have unmet dependencies: block_content.type.basic (block_content), comment.type.comment (comment), contact.form.feedback (contact), core.entity_form_display.block_content.basic.default (text), core.entity_form_display.node.article.default (image.style.thumbnail, comment, image, path, text), core.entity_form_display.node.page.default (path, text), core.entity_form_display.user.user.default (image.style.thumbnail, image), core.entity_view_display.node.article.default (image.style.wide, comment, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss (core.entity_view_mode.node.rss), core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, image.style.medium, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, text), editor.editor.basic_html (ckeditor5, editor), field.field.block_content.basic.body (field.storage.block_content.body, text, field), field.field.comment.comment.comment_body (field.storage.comment.comment_body, text, field), field.field.node.article.body (field.storage.node.body, text, field), field.field.node.article.comment (comment, field), field.field.node.article.field_image (image, field), field.field.node.article.field_tags (field), field.storage.node.comment (comment, node, field), field.storage.node.field_image (file, image, node, field), field.storage.node.field_tags (node, taxonomy, field), field.storage.user.user_picture (file, image, field), filter.format.basic_html (editor, filter), filter.format.restricted_html (filter), node.type.article (node), taxonomy.vocabulary.tags (taxonomy), user.role.anonymous (comment, contact, filter, search), user.role.authenticated (comment, contact, filter, search, shortcut), user.role.content_editor (comment, contextual, file, node, path, taxonomy, toolbar, tour) in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 100 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException.php).
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('standard', Array) (Line: 526)
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard') (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard') (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 1657)
install_install_profile(Array) (Line: 698)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 569)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 119)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 48)**

Версия Drupal - 10.0.9

В интернете нашёл информацию, что эта ошибка характерна для 7-8 версий Drupal, но у меня аж 10... Да и исправить как - непонятно. Уже 3 раза пробовал заново переустановить. В чём может быть причина?